# What is the best way to ingest document in Marklogic database so that the size doesn't increase much in database?

Tags: marklogic

In Marklogic whenever we ingest any documents the size of the documents increase by 1.5 times. Do we have any way so that the size doesn't increase?

Comment: There are a lot of factors that affect overall database size (indexes and how well documents compress). Are the documents mostly the same type and structure? Are they mostly XML, JSON, text, or binary docs? There are some options that you can disable, but it would come at the expense of functionality. In order to make search and retrieval faster, that usually comes at the expense of disk and/or memory.

Comment: If there are particular documents that you know you don't need indexed for search and query, you could store them as `binary()` nodes.

Comment: Just to put it in perspective, 1.5 times is a pretty good (small) ratio for search engines.

Answer (score 3):

The size of the document on disk is pretty much always going to be dependent on how many (and what kind of) term list indexes you have switched on. The general rule of thumb is that the more indexes you have enabled the more disk space MarkLogic is going to utilise.

Also note that we apply hashing to the indexes and we also apply compression to the documents so MarkLogic is trying it's best to keep the document and index sizes at a minimum.

Comment: The biggest impact is probably the universal index, which is the core behind the full-text search capabilities. It is turned on for documents databases by default. You could turn it off completely, but that is very uncommon for documents databases. It is typically only disabled for modules, schemas, and triggers databases.